# psql error: could not stat file- unknown error

Tags: copy, psql

I’m using psql copy command to copy csv file from a directory to my targeted table in a postgres database.It successfully works if my file is less that 1 GB but if file is bigger than 1 GB I get the error: could not stat file “mydata.csv” : unknown error

I trier a small file, less that 1 GB , copy psql command works executed using a bat file